# Elasticsearch DSL Query for Update

Tags: elasticsearch

I understand that I am able to update a particular document by  http://localhost:9200/[index_name]/[index_type]/[_id], but I have document where the _id has # symbols which Sense couldn't find them.

Understand that the Query DSL will be able to perform a search where I am able to indicate the _id not in the URL. 
Resource: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

Can I check with you, how can I do the same for updating document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to put the ID in the URL, the only option you have is to use the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), like this:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": ["2323#23423"]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "do some update here"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am using Elasticsearch version 1.3.3 and I think this version don't have the _update_by_query. I used "index/_update_by_query" and it throws error: "InvalidTypeNameException[mapping type name [_update_by_query] can't start with '_']", status 400.

Comment: In that case, you can use the [update by query 2.2.0 plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) that worked for ES 1.3.3

Comment: thank you for the response. The _update_by_query won't be able to create new document if 2323#23423 is not in the index. May I ask you what about the creation of new document?

Comment: Your question didn't mention anything about creating the document if it was missing.

Comment: No, I don't have luck on this. I will create a new question regarding the creation of the document. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use localhost:9200/index/type/ID%23, %23 for #

So if '_id' is 10, url will look like localhost:9200/index/type/10%23

Comment: There might be other special characters that the users might enter, so I would like to ask whether is there any workaround rather than having the _id on the url. Thank you for the response.